# Growth Rates of F(n) vs. F(n) + F(n-1) + ... F(1)

Tags: asymptotics, recursion

I am trying to understand growth rates between a function and its sum recursively. For example I understand that if:

$F(n) = n$

Then the sum $n + (n - 1) + ... 2 + 1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ which is $O(n^2)$. Which means that $F(n) = O(sum)$.

However, I am having trouble understanding this concept for the function:

$F(n) = 2^n$

The answer is $F(n) = \Theta(sum)$ But I am not sure why it is $\Theta$ and not $O$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show by induction (or using the geometric series formula), that
$$2^1 + 2^2 + \ldots + 2^n = 2^{n+1} - 2$$
And you have that $2^{n+1} - 2 = 2(2^n - 1) = \Theta(2^n)$

Comment: Intuitively, when a function grows fast enough, the last value dominates all the earlier terms.  $2^n$ is like that-the last term in the sum is greater than the sum of all the earlier ones.  Polynomials are not like that.  The sum of $n^m$ is about $\frac 1{m+1}n^{m+1}$, one degree higher.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am guessing you can put some conditions on the derivative to achieve this, do you know which condition is sufficient?

Comment: It is essentially that the integral up to $n$ is about the same as the function at $n$, which is another way of saying the function is exponential.  It also means the derivative is about the same as the function, which is one definition of the exponential function.